# show error in same page for the form submission without using session and get

Tags: php, html

I have a form with three select input.if user doesnot select any of option i want to show error in same page. the user has to insert any of the three select input, user can select in all the input or just one or just two or all. if not i want to show error.

my code:

```
<form action="booking.php" method="POST">
<h1>SINGLE ROOM</h1>

Number of Rooms:
<select name="singleroom">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">0</option>  
<?php 

foreach($singleroom as $room):

for($i=1;$i<=$room['maxRoom'];$i++){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
<?php } 
endforeach;
?>

</select>

<h1>DOUBLE ROOM</h1>

Number of Rooms:
<select name="doubleroom">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">0</option>
    <?php 
foreach($doubleroom as $room):

for($i=1;$i<=$room['maxRoom'];$i++){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
<?php } 
endforeach;
?>

</select>

<h1>TRIPLE ROOM</h1>

Number of Rooms:
<select name="tripleroom">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">0</option>
<?php 
foreach($tripleroom as $room):

for($i=1;$i<=$room['maxRoom'];$i++){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
<?php } 
endforeach;
?>


</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

in booking.php i have verified if user has completed the requirement. if not i want to redirect to form page with error.
I dont want to use get and session since it brought some errors.

Comment: why not eliminating the errors you got when using a session or get params??

Comment: it also would be much better to validate the form _before_ sending it to server via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your **booking.php** add the follow code at start where you get form data.

```
if(!isset($_POST['singleroom']) && !isset($_POST['doubleroom']) && !isset($_POST['tripleroom'])){
    header("Location: your_form_page.php?error=1"); // redirect back to your page you are showing form.
}
```

In your form page where you show the form use this:

```
if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1){
    echo "Please select atleast one field";     // your error message you want to show
}
```